# ¿Cómo obtener los datos de una tabla basado en el menor valor de una columna?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

¿Alguien sabe como corregir este tipo de consulta para que la sintaxis sea correcta?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    setup_aoi 
WHERE 
    WO='"+WO+"' 
    AND 
    MIN(Pendiente_Enviar)"
```

Lo que se requiere es que la consulta busque un dato en una columna en donde habrán muchos datos para la misma (WO) pero de todos esos datos tiene que obtener solo el de menor valor en la columna (Pendiente enviar)

Sería algo así como `where WO AND Pendiente_enviar` cumplan la condición.

Comment: qué es `WO` y `Pendiente_Enviar` es una columna de la tabla?

Comment: si, ambos pertenecen a una tabla, son columnas de una base de datos, visto de otra forma, WO es similar a un ID y pendiente enviar es una condicion en donde tiene que encontrar el de menor valor

Comment: Fuera de la última comilla doble después de `Enviar)"` todo lo demás está sintácticamente correcto, si ya no te envía datos diría que es por la condición de `WO`

Comment: Si, lo mismo creí, la sintaxis pareciera estar bien pero cuando compila si realiza la consulta pero no obtiene el valor menor, osea, que al final no cumple la condición y el catch atrapa un error relacionado con la sintaxis

Comment: ¿Te manda error la consola de mysql o te arroja una consulta vacía? La mejor forma en como puedes probarlo sería ejecutar la consulta directamente sobre MySQL

Comment: Esto mas o menos es lo que muestra el error: you have an error in your sql syntax, check the manual that correspond to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near to "Pendiente_Enviar" at line 1

Comment: no estoy utilizando la consola de mysql, únicamente el netbeans desde donde hago la consulta, pero irónicamente si obtiene los valores correspondientes a la columna WO pero no filtra por la condición de buscar el menor valor que corresponde a la columna Pendiente enviar

Comment: `SELET * FROM setup_aoi WHERE WO = '"+WO+"' AND Pendiente_Enviar = (SELECT MIN(Pendiente_Enviar) FROM setup_aoi)`

Comment: hice una prueba y al ejecutar `MIN(columna_tabla) ` arroja el siguiente ERROR: **"No se permiten funciones de agregación en el WHERE**. ¿Cuál tipo de datos que contiene la columna `Pendiente_Enviar`?

Comment: son números reales, cantidades de producto para ser mas especifico, y esa columna es la clave para poder realizar la consulta siguiente, ya que de ahí proviene el dato que me permite continuar insertando información en la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por tratarse de una función de agregación no puedes usarla directamente dentro de un `WHERE` como buscas hacerlo en tu condición. Lo que puedes hacer es cambiar un poco la consulta, para que esta función quede dentro de una subconsulta `SELECT`, de esta forma te regresará el dato que buscas, y podrás compararlo dentro del `WHERE` de tu consulta original.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    setup_aoi
WHERE
    WO = '"+WO+"'
AND
    Pendiente_Enviar = (SELECT MIN(Pendiente_Enviar) FROM setup_aoi)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por las sugerencias, lo voy a intentar...

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias, fue excelente ver esa solución... 100% agradecido...